# How to parse XML-Response in C# from Nokia-HERE Geocoding REST API

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, here-api

**INTRO**

I am writing a WinForm application in C# where I am requesting a map position (latitude/longitude) for a given address.

I utilize the Nokia HERE Geocoding REST API and request an XML, which I then try to parse. The following API call is from the Nokia docs:

**REST API CALL**

```
http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=8&searchtext=425+W+Randolph+Chicago
```

This API call returns an XML stream, which looks like this (shortend):

**XML RESPONSE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Search xmlns:ns2="http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Search-Search/4">
    <Response>
        <MetaInfo>
            <Timestamp>2014-12-15T10:11:29.197Z</Timestamp>
        </MetaInfo>
        <View xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns2:SearchResultsViewType">
            <ViewId>0</ViewId>
            <Result>
                <Relevance>1.0</Relevance>
                <MatchLevel>houseNumber</MatchLevel>
                <MatchQuality>
                    <City>1.0</City>
                    <Street>0.9</Street>
                    <HouseNumber>1.0</HouseNumber>
                </MatchQuality>
                <MatchType>pointAddress</MatchType>
                <Location>
                    <LocationId>NT_krOz+rwboyk4Jvih55MwPB_425</LocationId>
                    <LocationType>address</LocationType>
                    <DisplayPosition>
                        <Latitude>41.8838692</Latitude>
                        <Longitude>-87.6389008</Longitude>
                    </DisplayPosition>
                    <NavigationPosition>
                        <Latitude>41.8844719</Latitude>
                        <Longitude>-87.6387711</Longitude>
                    </NavigationPosition>
                </Location>
            </Result>
        </View>
    </Response>
</ns2:Search>
```

As I am only really interested in extracting the content within the `<NavigationPosition>` node, I thought I could code as follows:

**C# CODE SNIPPET TO RETRIEVE XML**

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=8&searchtext=425+W+Randolph+Chicago");
req.Method = "GET";

req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

req.Timeout = 5000;
var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

var ms = new MemoryStream();
var rs = resp.GetResponseStream();
if (rs != null)
{
    var buf = new byte[4096];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = rs.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    rs.Close();
}

var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));

var status = xml.SelectNodes("/ns2:Search/Response/View/Result[1]/Location/NavigationPosition");
if (status.Count == 1)
{

    var lat = xml.SelectNodes("/ns2:Search/Response/View/Result[1]/Location/NavigationPosition/Latitude");
    var lng = xml.SelectNodes("/ns2:Search/Response/View/Result[1]/Location/NavigationPosition/Longitude");
}
```

I had to learn that I cannot parse this particular XML this way since it contains a namespace prefix `(ns2)`. So I added the namespace manager:

**ADDED NAMESPACEMANAGER**

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmanager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
nsmanager.AddNamespace("ns2", "http://www.navteq.com/lbsp/Search-Search/4");
```

And changed the xpath query `xml.SelectNodes()` to:

**UPDATED C# CODE**

```
var status = xml.SelectNodes("/ns2:Search/Response/View/Result[1]/Location/NavigationPosition", nsmanager);
if (status.Count == 1)
{

    var lat = xml.SelectNodes("/ns2:Search/Response/View/Result[1]/Location/NavigationPosition/Latitude", nsmanager);
    var lng = xml.SelectNodes("/ns2:Search/Response/View/Result[1]/Location/NavigationPosition/Longitude", nsmanager);
}
```

**MY QUESTION**

Now, with the NS manager added, I am able to read and parse the XML response.

Since I am only interested in the lat/lng values of the first result (there can be more than one result, more than one result-node), is there any way to avoid a possible overhead (introduced by the namespace manager maybe) and to access the lat/lng values more easily? Can my c# code to retrieve the XML response be rewritten to be more efficient since I don't need to parse the entire response?

Comment: Do you have to use `XmlDocument`? Namespaces are a lot simpler to use with LINQ to XML...

Comment: @JonSkeet no, XmlDocument is not necessary. I've used it many times before (i.e. with the Google Geocoder) and thus implemented it in this project. Will look into LINQ - thanks for that hint!

Comment: Additionally, I would recommend *just* parsing from the stream, whether you're using LINQ to XML or XmlDocument. There's no need to copy the stream to a `MemoryStream`, convert it to a string and then parse that.

Comment: You can streamline the response by setting the `reponseattributes` and `locationattributes` parameters in the request  e.g. [http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&gen=8&searchtext=TEXT &responseattributes=none&locationattributes=none&gen=8](http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=8&searchtext=425+W+Randolph+Chicago&responseattributes=none&locationattributes=none&gen=8)

Comment: Nice, @JasonFox! I missed that (though I had a thorough look at the docs, I had thought). Thanks! I did not see (and read) anything about the default behaviour of `reponseattributes` and `locationattributes` - by the looks of the documentation, setting them to none will no give any location (not even lat/lng)...

Comment: It is still not clear to me how to best use `Linq to Xml` in conjunction with namespaces on this matter. I am happy to accept an answer with a short code snippet demonstrating the best use (maybe including async loading of the Xml from the REST API). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The smallest/shortest response you can get is by setting locationattributes and responseattributes to "none", combine that with "maxresults=1" to only get the first, best result based on our input. See below for example.

http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=8&maxresults=1&locationattributes=none&responseattributes=none&searchtext=425%20W%20Randolph%20Chicago

This still includes the navigation position (always attached to a street segment) and the display position. Later being the parcel centroid aka roof top for house number precise results.

Comment: Thank you for giving the `maxresults=1` hint. The HERE API docs are - at least to me - a bit misleading. I interpreted the description given for `maxresults` as pagination directives. However, using maxresult=1 gives me just one result (the one with the highest probability, I guess).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Sebastian, we will take this and improve the documentation for the next release.

Comment: Philip, nice to see a HERE developer here! Does HERE have a German sales representative you could hook me up with (I see, you're based in Frankfurt). Frohe Weihnachten!

Comment: Hi Sebastian, sure thing. I can't find a way to connect with you here. My full name is Philip Hubertus. Please look me up and get in touch. 
Alternatively you can sign up on our developer portal for a Geocoder plan. This page has the link to the plan: https://developer.here.com/geocoder
And here is a deep link: https://developer.here.com/get-started#/10134037